# Unity 2D collider is not behaving properly. I cant move through/on the one block below the 2D collider

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d-games, collider

So I was trying to make a tile base movement and suddenly came encountered this problem with collider2D.
So I set up a tile size 2D collider for that pole there in the image but then there's one problem.
I suddenly noticed that I cannot move through or on the one tile/block below the 2D Collider.

Note that the character don't have any collider 2d or rigidbody 2d.
The character is relying on function `private bool notBlocked(Vector3 movePosition)` to stop my character from moving and stop animation when blocked.

I highlighted the block/tile where I can't move. There's no collider there so I don't know why my character can't walk through/on it
[image: Cant move on this block "Highlighted Red"]

but then when I try it on the block on the top of the collider, it works same as the left and right tile/block around the collider.

[image: Can move to the block in top of every collider]

So this is the code I used for movement and stop movement when colliding.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float moveSpeed;
    public LayerMask SolidObjectLayer;

    private bool isMoving;
    private Vector2 input;
    private Animator animator;

    private void Update()
    {
        InputMove();
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void InputMove()
    {
        if (!isMoving)
        {

            input.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            input.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

            if (input.x != 0) input.y = 0;

            if (input != Vector2.zero)
            {
                animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", input.x);
                animator.SetFloat("Vertical", input.y);

                var movePos = transform.position;
                movePos.x += input.x;
                movePos.y += input.y;

                if (notBlocked(movePos))
                    StartCoroutine(Move(movePos));
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            moveSpeed = 6f;
            animator.speed = 1.5f;
        }

        else
        {
            moveSpeed = 4f;
            animator.speed = 1f;
        }
        animator.SetBool("isMoving", isMoving);
    }

    IEnumerator Move(Vector3 movePos)
    {
        isMoving = true;
        while((movePos - transform.position).sqrMagnitude > Mathf.Epsilon)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, movePos, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }
        transform.position = movePos;
        isMoving = false;
    }

    private bool notBlocked(Vector3 movePosition)
    {
        if(Physics2D.OverlapCircle(movePosition, 0.2f, SolidObjectLayer) != null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I don't know if It has something to do with "private bool isBlocked()", but it's the function that I used to stop the character from moving any further if being block.

Comment: how big is your character collider? looks like the head is colliding with the pillar

Comment: there's no collider on my character. It uses ```OverlapCircle``` to stop character from moving through object that has collider 2D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I somehow manage to figure out how to fix it.
So the character can only move on block that has no collider
[image]

So It means that if that yellow point is going straight through a collider then it will prevent my character from moving. So it seems like the OverlapCircle cast from the center of the character or the pivot so I changed the pivot of my character a little bit lower.

So as you can see here the problem is the OverLapCircle is trying to walk in the collider
but then the script is preventing it from happening and preventing me from moving on the time below the tile.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems the collider on your character is too big. If the collider covers the entire character, then the head would collide with the pillar. To fix this, you can click on this button:
[image]
And edit the collider so it is only the bottom square where the feet are. This will prevent the head from colliding with the pillar.

Comment: The thing is... My character don't have any Collider 2D. So it's relying on ```OverlapCircle```  to not move on any object that has collider2D

Comment: Oh. Then when you say `var movePos = transform.position`, you should say `var movePos = transform.position - (Vector3.up * -0.5f)` so you plug the location of the bottom square the player is standing into your check function.